# A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution in Android

Tags: android

I am using below  configuration and version in build.gradle file
app level build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion '25.2.9519653'
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mypackage.android"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 69
        versionName "3.20"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        }
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        /* ndk {
             // config you want to support device
             //abiFilters 'arm86-v8a', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
             abiFilters  'x86','x86_64'
         }*/
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments '-DANDROID_STL=c++_static'
            }
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsCollectionEnabled:"false"]
        }

    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            outputFileName = "RoveDashCam-${variant.versionName}-${new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}.apk"
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }


    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
            version '3.22.1'
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'rovedashcam'
            keyPassword 'rovedashcam'
            storeFile file('rovedashcam.jks')
            storePassword 'rovedashcam'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation project(path: ':multiimagepicker')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    implementation 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:android-otpview-pinview:2.1.2'

   
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.8.3'
    implementation 'com.github.klaviyo.klaviyo-android-sdk:analytics:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.klaviyo.klaviyo-android-sdk:push-fcm:2.0.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

build.gradle Project level

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
    }
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.31'

    ext.anko_version='0.10.8'
    ext.daggerLibVersion = "2.15"
    ext.daggerAndroidLibVersion = "2.15"
    ext.room_version = "1.1.1"
    ext.mockitoVersion = '2.10.0'
    ext.hamcrestVersion='1.4-atlassian-1'
    ext.roomVersion = '2.2.2'
    ext.lifecycle_version = '2.1.0'
    ext.daggerVer= "2.30.1"
    ext.archComponentsVersion="2.2.0"
    ext.biometric_version = "1.0.1"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
     
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
        classpath 'com.vanniktech:gradle-maven-publish-plugin:0.15.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

when i build code i am getting below error :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:187)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:268)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:185)
```

Please help me how to fix this issue i tried to find from google but not able to find correct solution please suggest me where i am doing mistake .
Thanks